# Error: Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with babel-plugin-emotion. while trying to style checkbox with emotion and CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emotion

I am trying to style a Checkbox with emotion, and i need to apply a style like this :

```
input[type = 'checkbox'] + .someclass {
   ....
}
```

in emotion, based on some googling, i found that you could do something like this :

```
StyledCheckBox = styled.input`
    & + {() => StyledPlaceHolder} {
     ... 
   }
`;
```

But i keep getting an error :

```
Error: Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with babel-plugin-emotion.
```

As per the docs, i tried to use macros instead of babel-plugin-emotion but the error persists.

Here is a codesandbox i made mimicing the error :- https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cache-kg9s9

In the codesandbox preview you will see it as a cross-origin error, but if you open the chrome console you can see the error i mentioned. Furthermore, you can download it and run the code on your local machine to see the error message on the browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated.